“Load failed” on fetch request, but only in the Instagram app
I use a form on my WordPress site. The data is sent asyncronously to wp-ajax.php. This works fine in all browsers, but in the Instagram app browser in iOS I get the error “Load failed”. The interesting thing is that the request still arrived at the server and was processed correctly. What could be the reason for this?
<script>
    document.querySelector('.gm_courseform').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const form = this;
        form.classList.add('sending');

        const submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_button');
        const originalButtonText = submitButton.textContent;
        submitButton.disabled = true;
        submitButton.textContent = "Wird geladen...";
        document.querySelectorAll(".form-message").forEach(el => el.remove());
        const formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append('action', 'create_booking');

        fetch("<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
                    "Pragma": "no-cache",
                    "Expires": "0"
                },
                body: formData,
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
              // [...]
            })
            .catch(error => {
             // [...]
    });
</script>


'I get the error “Load failed”.' - from where/what? Are you talking about an error message you yourself are triggering, from within the catch block? Or some error message produces by the browser/webview itself?

Excuse me. It is the browser's error message that I catch in the .catch(error) block

Update: The problem is that Instagram (I don't know why) can't open “/wp-admin”. Since the url of wp-ajax is “/wp-admin/wp-ajax.php”, Instagram could not get the response.
Instead of wp-ajax I now use the wordpress rest-api. So it works problemols again.

Interesting; good find! I'm guessing that is perhaps a restriction they introduced because someone tried to run a phishing campaign trying to target WP admins via Instagram, or sth like that.
